# Pandas query "&"-Operator behaves like logical NAND

Tags: python, pandas, filter, logical-operators

i have got the following issue. I want to dynamically create queries to filter pandas data frames without specifying columns manually beforehand.

I found the following code snippet to do so, all data is of type String:

```
columnList=[col1, col1, col1, col2]
filterList=[va1, val2, val3, val4]
query = ' & '.join(f'`{i}!=repr{k}' for i, k in zip(columnList,filterList))
df=df.query(query)
```

However when I run my code the resulting dataframe looks like all filters have been applied one by one but not as a unified "filter rule chain" connected by the "&" operator. It rather looks like i would have applied a "NAND" operator to me.

In pandas both `and` and `&` should act like the logical NOR right?

Comment: The syntax around the `repr` looks dubious... formatting issues? Anyway, if I fix that, I get the results I expect. Could you add a small hard-coded dataframe to the question, along with actual and expected results?

Answer (score 0):

With [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar), you can manipulate the expressions used for filtering directly:

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tibble, filter
[2022-03-28 10:49:15][datar][WARNING] Builtin name "filter" has been overriden by datar.
>>> df = tibble(
...     c1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
...     c2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
... )
>>> 
>>> columnList=["c1", "c1", "c1", "c2"]
>>> filterList=["a", "b", "c", "d"]
>>> 
>>> expr = None
>>> for col, val in zip(columnList, filterList):
...     if expr is None:
...         expr = f[col] != val
...     else:
...         expr = expr & (f[col] != val)
... 
>>> df >> filter(expr)
        c1       c2
  <object> <object>
4        e        e
```